# Interpolate a variable into a regular expression

Tags: regex, raku

I am used to Perl but a Perl 6 newbie

I want to host a regular expression in a text variable, like I would have done in perl5:

```
my $a = 'abababa';
my $b = '^aba';
if ($a =~ m/$b/) {
        print "True\n";
} else {
        print "False\n";
}
```

But if I do the same in Perl6 it doesn't work:

```
my $a = 'abababa';
my $b = '^aba';

say so $a ~~ /^aba/;  # True
say so $a ~~ /$b/;    # False
```

I'm puzzled... What am I missing?

Answer (score 5):

You need to have a closer look at [Quoting Constructs](https://docs.perl6.org/language/quoting).

For this case, enclose the part of the LHS that is a separate token with angle brackets or `<{` and `}>`:

```
my $a = 'abababa';
my $b = '^aba';
say so $a ~~ /<$b>/;       # True, starts with aba
say so $a ~~ /<{$b}>/;     # True, starts with aba

my $c = '<[0..5]>'
say so $a ~~ /<$c>/;       # False, no digits 1 to 5 in $a
say so $a ~~ /<{$c}>/;     # False, no digits 1 to 5 in $a
```

[image]

Another story is when you need to pass a variable into a limiting quantifier. That is where you need to only use braces:

```
my $ok = "12345678";
my $not_ok = "1234567";
my $min = 8;
say so $ok ~~ / ^ \d ** {$min .. *} $ /;         # True, the string consists of 8 or more digits
say so $not_ok ~~ / ^ \d ** {$min .. *} $ /;     # False, there are 7 digits only
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that doesent work, the expression matches everything:

Comment: @mmzz Please explain what you mean. Didn't you want to get True as output for the `'abababa'` string?

Comment: @viktor-stribiżew yes indeed, but with ${b} I got True with any pattern, even "xxxx". my $a = 'abababa'; my $c = 'xxxxxxx'; say so $a ~~ /{$c}/; #True

Answer (score 4):

Is there a reason why you don't pick the [regex object](https://docs.perl6.org/language/regexes#index-entry-quote_%2F_%2F-quote_rx-quote_m-Lexical_Conventions) for these types of uses?

```
my $a = 'abababa';
my $b = rx/^aba/;

say so $a ~~ /^aba/;  # True
say so $a ~~ $b;     # True
```